# Ceiling rose wiring

Tags: wiring, lighting

Wiring diagrams of two cable ceiling roses, look like this

[image]

Yet when I look at the wiring in one of ours, it has this arrangement:

[image]

It looks as if the live and neutral from the switch and in wires are wired together. Light and switch work fine, but given the difference with the text book writing diagram, I worry that there light is incorrectly wired.

Any thoughts?

Ben

Comment: do not look at the colors, use a meter to determine the function

Comment: I can't really tell what I'm looking at in the photo  could you either provide a better-lit picture or draw it?

Comment: The diagram you show first seems to say that the fixture is controlled by a switch loop. If it was instead wired with power to the switch and then to the lamp, the loop wires won't exist. If the same circuit powers something else, there may be an outgoing cable as well..

Comment: @keshlam - UK lighting predominantly uses power to the ceiling, not to the switch. The switch is just itself a loop [confusing terminology, I'm aware] live out, switched live back. It should have a tag to differentiate, but no-one ever does.

Comment: In the US switch loops are less common, perhaps because we have more full basements. There is a tagging convention (switched hot return from the loop is canonically the white wire with it's end blackened with electrical tape) but here too tagging is less common than it should be and you may have to guess from context and/or test. (I wonder if this was easier before NMC, when you could run an odd-colored wire through the conduit to make very clear that something more complicated was being done?)

Comment: Better photo greatly appreciated!

Answer (score -1):

As it works just fine, we can assume the wiring is 'correct' for a given definition of correct.

If you look carefully, you'll see that rather than joint on the Loop, they've done it externally in a spare bit of terminal block. Who knows why, when there's one right there already.

What else they appear to have done is run the drop to the switch from the neutral rather than the live. Again, odd but actually electrically equivalent.
It's also been wired as a spur, & doesn't go off to any other lighting.  This is fine, only plug sockets need to be on a ring, lights can spur. This is also why you'll end up with two empty terminals, one in Loop, one in Neutral.

To put it back properly, your three-wire cable is your 'mains in' permanent live from the circuit. Earth is fine, but Live goes to Loop, Neutral goes to N.
Your other 2-wire cable is the drop to the switch. Live goes to Loop, neutral to L.
Your lamp fitting wiring then goes Live to L, Neutral to N [& Earth to Earth of course, if present].
Done. You now match the picture.

I'd have a look at whatever else they've DIY'd around the house, just in case of more surprises.

Comment: and that would be a perfect short circuit

Comment: Really? How? Please elucidate. The original, as posted by the OP works, but is bass-ackwards. This just returns it to 'expected'.

Comment: Looking at it again, again: The white connected between red of one cable and black of the other, and the red in this pair appears to have a piece of tape (now peeling off) to indicate that it is switched hot. So assuming that is acting as a splice/junction, what we're looking at appears to be the diagram others have shown but with red taking the role of blue, black taking the role of brown, and the lamp would have been attached using the other screws in the blocks labelled N and L. Thanks for leaning on my to take a third look at the photo!

Comment: There is no white wire in UK domestic circuits. What you can see is a black wire with a bit of paint/plaster/crud on it. As to the rest, I've already answered as to how it needs to be reconfigured.